# Define Command-C as copy and Command-V as paste global in debian

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I'm running Debian 9.3.0 in VirtualBox on macOS 10.13.3.

I want all applications in debian to interpret <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as copy and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> as paste, as they are defined in macOS. Note: debian calls the macOS <kbd>command</kbd> key <kbd>Super</kbd>.

I changed terminal to behave this way by mapping the opening of notifications to what paste defaults to, namely, from <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to <kbd>Cntl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. This freed <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and enabled me to map it to terminal's paste.

Other debian applications, such as LibreOffice don't even seem to define the <kbd>Super</kbd> key although LibreOffice in macOS does. In short, I have an Apple macBookPro keyboard that macOS applications use consistently and I want debian to use it the way macOS does. Can I do this?

Comment: Many applications on Unix system have their own keymappings for various things, such as `Y` ("yank line") and `P`/`p` ("paste above/below") in Vi and completely different ones in the Emacs editor. However, I'm not sure how the GUI-only applications do their key mappings, but my feeling is that it has to be done on an application by application basis.

Comment: Related: [Binding Super+C Super+V to Copy and Paste](https://superuser.com/questions/385748/binding-superc-superv-to-copy-and-paste)

Comment: There are mapping for kde, and probably gnome. There is also a lower level X11 mapping where you map super to another key (e.g. ctrl). There is also (probably) a way to map any key combination to any other.