# Define <Super>C to copy etc

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts

I am running Ubuntu 18.04

I am trying to remap the default Ubuntu shortcut of Ctrl+C to be Super+C, as well as paste, cut, select all, undo, and redo.

I DO NOT want to just change Ctrl to be Super and vice versa. I only want those specific shortcuts changed.

I have tried the Gnome tweak tool, and the dconf-editor, and the various answers in [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423678/define-command-c-as-copy-and-command-v-as-paste-global-in-debian).

Every single thing on Google no longer works, due to the changes they made in 18.04.